# jQuery - .load() each incremental id (ex: content1, content2, etc.)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Wasn't quite sure how to ask this, but anyways.
I am automatically adding divs (in php) depending on the id's stored in an array, and I'd like to refresh every existing div with a different value.  Here's an example of what the divs look like:

```
<div class="panel-heading" >
    <h4 class="panel-title" id="reload$device_id">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse$device_id">Data: $device_data</a>
    </h4>
</div>
```

I'm trying to reload the elements with the id "reload$device_id" (currently have 2 different id's, so it'd be reload1 and reload2).

Thank you for your help!

p.s: first time posting a question, not sure how this will work

Edit1: had a <=device_id_list.length instead, quick typo was fixed.

Edit2: Current code, pretty similar, only reloads first one :/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var device_id_list = <?php echo json_encode($device_id_list);?>;
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug.  without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
    setInterval(function() {
    for (var i = 1; i < device_id_list.length + 1; i++) {
        $("#reload" + i).load("reload_data.php?device=" + i);
    }
    }, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try: `for (var i = 1; i < device_id_list.length + 1; i++) {`

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" to the title.  Please post your solution below as an answer and "accept" it.  This is how everyone will know it contains an final answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't aware of this, I'll post my solution tonight.Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my problem wasn't on the javascript portion of my script, but rather when I was filling up the $device_id_list array. I wasn't doing it correctly, hence why it wasn't reloading all of the divs.

Here's my javascript anyways:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var device_id_list = <?php echo json_encode($device_id_list);?>;
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug.  without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
    setInterval(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < device_id_list.length; i++) {
        var device_id = device_id_list[i];
        $("#reload" + (device_id)).load("reload_data.php?device=" + (device_id));
    }
    }, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Its seems you echo out `json_encode($device_id_list)` and use php in javascript just to use `device_id_list.length` in for loop !!  if I'm right .. you can use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
      $('[div^="reload"]').each(function(){
         $(this).load('reload_data.php');
      });
    }, 5000); 
  });
</script>
```

hope it help

Comment: I'm a newb when it comes to javascript, just started using it recently in order to refresh my page lol. Thanks for the reply, I'll try this first thing tomorrow afternoon after my class :)

Comment: @brother6 never mind We were all newb in one day .. Good Luck :)

Comment: doesn't seem to be working at the moment, I'll look into it and try to find something. Or if someone has another proposition :)

Comment: it also seems to slow the loading time of the web page, for some reason.